# Sudden overlapping of Appendinces

Tags: latex

While working today, after hours of tweaking and fixing with the latex markup and making things prettier in the work, I all of the suddenly, after a refresh saw this:

**All used packages:**

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pifont,mdframed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalise]{cleveref} % Better in-doc refs
\usepackage[title,toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} % Better figure and table placements
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath} % For using \text in equations
\usepackage{csquotes} % For blockquote
\usepackage[labelfont=it, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} % used to include pdf to appendicies
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

**Declaration and usage:**

```
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\fixappendix}{%
  \patchcmd{\l@subsection}{2.3em}{5.6em}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\cleardoublepage
\newpage
\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\fixappendix}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\appendixname~\arabic{subsection}}
```

Comment: Can you make ONE code block we can just copy&paste to reproduce your problem?

Comment: You should not look at what might or might not be a valid pdf as long as there are error. Overleaf tries very hard to hide them from you, but you must never ignore error messages.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I sorted it. I am sorry. `%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was caused by: `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`.